# Meaning/Format of RAW Image Data

Tags: fitting, image

I took photographs and I want to fit the (overall intensity or red intensity) of the photographs to a function of (x,y). I have some questions about how RAW data is structured. What is the difference between:

"Data"  array of color values
"RawData"   array of intensity values captured by the sensor

When I import the data, the dimensions of "RawData" are {2622, 3944} while the dimensions of "Data" are {2602, 3908, 3}. How do I interpret these?

If I only wanted the red channel for example, which data would I use and how would I obtain it? Would "RawData"'s every other value of every row and column or just the first elements of "Data"?

Additionally, I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on how to fit the data to: f(x,y).

Thank you in advanced for your help.