# What image adjustments are made when importing raw camera data?

Tags: image-processing, import, implementation-details

I am trying to use Mathematica to import and process raw camera data in the Canon CR2 format. What I would like is data which has a linear relationship to exposure. I am thinking that the closest I could get to that would be demosaiced data imported with gamma = 1. Can anyone tell me what preprocessing occurs for Import[imageFile] when the imageFile is a raw format?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the extension of your file? Have you checked the corresponding Docs page for your file extension?

Comment: The extension is .cr2. It is generally documented as a raw format, but I find no information on what processing does or doesn't happen as part of importing a raw format.

Comment: Looks like the `"RawImage"` element is what you need. But I'd be interested to know what processing is done by default.

Comment: Also `"ColorProfileData"` element can shed light on the encoding. Then you can use `ColorConvert` to convert to sRGB which on turn can be converted to linear RGB.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42153/280,  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144019/280

Comment: I am not sure this is possible.  You can get linear data *without* demosaicing, or you can get the final image (which is not linear). Or you can implement your own naïve demosaicing.  Would that work for your?